# What happens when I pass 0 as the second parameter of getline?

Tags: c, io, getline

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) states that the second parameter of the getline function is the

> Maximum number of characters to write to s

However, I've seen code like this:

```cpp
size_t linecap = 0;
ssize_t linelen;
linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp);
```

Won't this be reading 0 bytes from source? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Note: "cplusplus.com" looks like a site for C++, yet this is a C question.  Better to use C documentation for C than C++ ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not correct. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), (*emphasis mine*)

> If `*lineptr` is `NULL`, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case, the value in `*n` is ignored.)
>
> Alternatively, before calling `getline()`, `*lineptr` can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer `*n` bytes in size. If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, `getline()` resizes it with `realloc(3)`, updating `*lineptr` and `*n` as necessary.
>
> **In either case, on a successful call, `*lineptr` and `*n` will be updated to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.**

So, the initial value stored in the memory pointed to by the second argument has no effect on the actual scanning. After the value is scanned and filled into the buffer,

- the function return value will tell you the size of the scanned input in bytes.
- the value of `*n` will tell you the size of the buffer which was allocated to store the input (which is usually bigger than the size of the scanned input).

Comment: The size value will only be updated if *lintptr is null at first?

Comment: My Linux man page (dated 2017-09-15) says something similar but slightly different:  If  *lineptr  is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed. (The rest matches what you quoted.)

Comment: @LukeKong no, both the cases, check the emphasized part.

Comment: @TomKarzes I linked the online page I was referring to - but I guess that's OK - `free(NULL);` is well defined.

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed. Updated.

Comment: For free, "If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed."

Answer (score 2):

The idea of `getline` is that there is as few as possible reallocations, as calls to `malloc` tend to be expensive. Hence if you use `getline` repeatedly to read the lines in a file, reusing the same buffer and length, the buffer will be eventually grown to the size of the longest line in the file, and no reallocations will be needed for the lines succeeding the longest line.

But for that to work certain contracts must be followed - namely if `*lineptr` is **non-NULL** then it

- must be a pointer returned by `malloc`
- must have allocation size of at least `*n` bytes

Corollary: passing `0` in `*n` is fine under these 2 circumstances:

- if `*lineptr` is `NULL`
- `*lineptr` is *any* live pointer returned by `malloc` (as any pointer returned by `malloc` will have 0 bytes space).

in both cases `*n` will be updated to the length of the line, and the return value of `realloc(*lineptr, new_line_length_with_terminator)` (if successful) will have been assigned to `*lineptr`.

Of course